# Serving High Traffic Video Over Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I am trying to serve a single High-Res video to 30+ clients *exactly concurrently*. This is leading to a bottle-neck causing some clients to time-out, and some to experience considerable lag.

Right now – it is clear that each individual request is being processed separately so the server is sending many gigs/sec. Someone mentioned it may be possible to configure Nginx to recognize that the requests are all for the same asset, serve it once, and then let the router (we are running this server locally) send the file to all the devices.

Is this feasible and/or is there any other way to increase my throughput?

Here's my conig per request. It's very simple so far...

```
    upstream unicorn {
      server unix:/tmp/unicorn.todo.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default;
        root    /usr/local/var/rails/todo-after/public;

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri $uri/video @unicorn;
        location @unicorn {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://unicorn;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly self-hosting something like this isn't ideal, I recommend hosting the video on a CDN.  They can better handle things like heavy bandwidth and co-location for better latency.

Check out [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Rackspace CDN](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files)

**EDIT**

It appears as though [Nginx](http://nginx.com/products/streaming-media-delivery/) has some convenience functionality for streaming video.  You can limit the bandwidth on a single download to a multiple of the bit-rate of the video.

```
location /video/ {
  mp4;
  mp4_limit_rate        1.2; #1.2 times the bitrate of the video.
  mp4_limit_rate_after  15s; #After downloading 15s of video.
}
```

Comment: Problem is we're running local and portable. We need to run this internationally at places that may not have reliable access to the WWW.

Comment: Can you post your nginx.conf?

Comment: where is the video located on your file system?

Comment: Sorry my config file may actually be slightly different – it's on my external SSD which is at the office right now so I pulled an old one for this. I'm not actually using vagrant. I've edited to be truer to what I remember my final settings actually were. –
Suffice to say I've already confirmed that Nginx is serving the video, not unicorn.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong – But won't limiting the download rate just increase the amount my clients have to buffer? If I tell nginx to impose a limitation, I suppose it could prevent the pipeline from reach a point of being so clogged that it just stops working – but will it be at the cost of allowing anyone to download the video quickly?

Comment: Why would you want to send the whole video to clients if they stop watching after 30 seconds? There are a handful of scenarios depending on how the users interacts with the video that would determine the optimal strategy.  Can you give me more background on the video and how it will be viewed?

Comment: Since we are running this locally – and are in the room with all the clients, we will be insisting that they watch the entire video and actually have JS in place to ensure that they do so before they can move on to the next step.

Therefore, it is imperative that on our end – we allow them to watch the entire video, without interruption, and without a significant delay in initial load time (though we can certainly work with some)

Comment: The video itself will vary, but we can impose some restrictions as necessary. For instance – we are suggesting a file size of <=10mb. We can also refactor to a lower resolution if necessary, but we obviously want it to look as good as possible.

Comment: Also – the limit_rate appears to only be available for Nginx Plus Subscribers, which is not available for Unix set-up...

Comment: How large is the video? What size displays are you targeting? Can you describe the scenario of the app? Based on your description this seems like something that will be displayed at trade shows.

Answer (score -1):

S3 as a origin data storage is good enough. But to serve out of S3 directly cost you a lot.

Two options you have: CDN (CloudFront with S3 as origin) or Nginx S3 proxy.

First one is easy to setup, very efficient, geographically distributed but doesn't support specific features like URL masking, HTTP2/0 with multiplexing (aka SPDY), custom caching and custom authentication.

The second option is the opposite and provide you full freedom. Nginx S3 proxy is very strong, cheap and expenses friendly, just imagine someone tries to fetch a big video file over CDN thousand times, the bill increases proportionally. For some projects is not a problem.

So you choose what suits you better.

P.S. I recommend to serve big files on a separate machine with bigger upper limits for open files + utilise more Nginx workers.